# Local variables in a stack frame

Tags: assembly, stack

Suppose you have a stack frame...

```
push %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
subl $20, %esp

High (+)
+-------------+
|             |
|  old %ebp   |
|             |
|             |
+-------------+ %ebp
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
+-------------+ $esp
Low (-)
```

And suppose you take a double-word (4 bytes), and movl it to (%esp)...

```
movl $0x44415441, (%esp) #0x44415441 being "DATA" in hex for ASCII...
```

Does the stack look like this?

```
High (+)
+-------------+
|             |
|  old %ebp   |
|             |
|             |
+-------------+ %ebp
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
+-------------+
|      D      |
|      A      |
|      T      |
|      A      |
+-------------+ %esp
Low (-)
```

Or this?

```
High (+)
+-------------+
|             |
|  old %ebp   |
|             |
|             |
+-------------+ %ebp
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
+-------------+ %esp
|      D      |
|      A      |
|      T      |
|      A      |
+-------------+
Low (-)
```

Also, would the four bytes be laid out like this in memory...

```
High (+)
+-------------+
|      D      |
|      A      |
|      T      |
|      A      |
+-------------+
Low (-)
```

Or like this...

```
High (+)
+-------------+
|      A      |
|      T      |
|      A      |
|      D      |
+-------------+
Low (-)
```

Comment: Even if the stack grows down, a memory access writes data from the specified address up. IA32e is a Little Endian architecture, so the low byte goes in the low address. When you do `mov DWORD [esp], 01234567h`, you have `67h -> [esp], 45h -> [esp+1], 32h -> [esp+2], 01h -> [esp+3]`. So your second and (maybe?) third pictures are the correct ones. Also note, out of interest, that for the sake of  `push/pop`, the stack model is Full Descending.

Comment: Thank you for answering. You should truly answer. Could you perhaps elaborate upon what you mean by "Full Descending"?

Comment: It simply means that a `push` is a *decrement stackpointer, store value* and a `pop` is *read value, increment stackpointer*. The two operation performed by the `push/pop` instruction could be very well swapped (giving an Empty Descending stack). The terminology comes from [arm](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473c/Cacbgchh.html) where you can choose the stack model.

Comment: Just one more question... If I have an item pushed onto a blank stack, %esp pointing to byte -4, and I create an eight byte stack frame wherein %ebp = -4 and %esp = -12, if I push another item onto the stack, is %esp set to -8, or does it remain at -12?

Comment: I I have understood you correctly, *esp* should be at -16. Since `push` decrement the stack pointer by 4 (when you push a DWORD).

Comment: Okay, so %esp is at -16, has the pushed value been placed between %esp, and %esp+4?

Comment: Yes. Anyway, the simplest way to understand these things is to make a sample program and inspect its stack and registers with a debugger. You'll learn a lot. Also every instruction is fully (more or less) documented in the Intel Manual.

Comment: Understood. Many thanks!